# How do electrons rearrange themselves after a fusion reaction?

Tags: electrons, nuclear-physics, fusion

The hydrogen atoms can fused inside Sun core into helium without considering about the free electrons, however what about special* cases where two neutrally charged hydrogen atoms collide and fused together? I meant how do the electrons rearrange themselves or are stripped by the powerful nuclear force?

- this won't happen in the lab or collider but I'm just curious.

Answer (score 4):

The interior of the Sun where fusion occurs is hot enough that all hydrogen atoms have ionized. So there are no hydrogen atoms; it’s all a plasma of nuclei and electrons.

Answer (score 1):

The reaction between two neutral atoms is the same as between two charged ones. Thus we expect several MeV to come out. The ionization energy of hydrogen is 13.6 eV. So those electrons are *gone*.